# Dynamically inserting list items to listview in android

Tags: android, listview

Friends i'm new to android and learning on my own. I was creating invoice manager app for learning. Here products are added by the admin and that is working fine. User has only permission to create invoice. When user arrives into create_invoice activity he has set of frame layouts in which one is for adding items. When user presses the frame layout he is made to see another activity where he can find all set of list items along with the product price in List view which admin has added. Now when user presses an item he is again brought back to create_invoice activity and a alert box appears which asks the qty required. When user enters the qty and clicks OK button, for the first the list item is displayed properly as i require. But when i add second item, 1st item gets replaced. So now my problem is how can i resolve this problem.. Guys please help me. Codes you people find may be very silly but i'm still learning. Thanks in advance.

## Create_invoice activity

```
 //data from activity invoice add_item
  product_name = intent.getStringExtra("product_name");
  product_price = intent.getDoubleExtra("product_price",0);
  //product_qty = intent.getIntExtra("product_qty",0);
  product_code = intent.getIntExtra("product_code",0);

  if(product_name!= null && product_price!= 0 && product_code!= 0)
  {
    try {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Product Qty");
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(Create_invoice.this);
      view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialoglayout_invoice,null);
        builder.setView(view);

 builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
  EditText etxt_dialog_qty=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id. 
   etxt_dialog_qty);

                int qty = Integer. parseInt (etxt_dialog_qty.getText(). 
             toString().trim());

                invoice_product_list products = new invoice_product_list 
  (product_name, product_price, qty, product_code);

         //arraylist
        ArrayList<invoice_product_list> productList = new ArrayList<>();

         //customAdapter
     customAdapterInvoice = new custom_adapter_invoice 
   (Create_invoice.this, productList);

                customAdapterInvoice.add(products);

                customAdapterInvoice.notifyDataSetChanged();

                //listview in create_invoice activity
                listView_additem = (ListView) 
 findViewById(R.id.listview_additem);

                listView_additem.setAdapter(customAdapterInvoice);

                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new 
      DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
}
```

## customAdapter

```
  public class custom_adapter_invoice extends ArrayAdapter 
   <invoice_product_list> {

   public custom_adapter_invoice(Context context,   
  ArrayList<invoice_product_list> product_details) {
   super(context, R.layout.custom_row_invoice_item, product_details);
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
View view =   
layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_invoice_item,parent,false);

invoice_product_list products = getItem(position);

TextView txt_product_name = 
(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_name);

TextView txt_product_price = 
 (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_price);

  TextView txt_product_qty = 
 (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_qty);

  TextView txt_product_code = 
  (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_code);

  txt_product_name.setText(products.getProduct_name());

txt_product_price.setText(String.valueOf(products.getProduct_price()));

txt_product_qty.setText(String.valueOf(products.getProduct_qty()));

txt_product_code.setText(String.valueOf(products.getProduct_code()));

return view;

}
```

## create invoice activity

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.tournonstop.m.invoicemanager.Create_invoice"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_create_invoice">

  <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/invoice_frame_company">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/company_name"
        android:id="@+id/txt_company_name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/invoice_date"
        android:id="@+id/txt_invoice_date"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/invoice_no"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"/>

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/invoice_frame_client"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/to"
        android:id="@+id/txt_to"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/txt_client_address"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/client_hint"/>

</FrameLayout>

 ----listview to add items-----
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/invoice_frame_add_item"
    android:clickable="true">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/listview_additem"
        android:divider="#040404" />
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/invoice_frame_sub_total">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/total_label"
        android:id="@+id/txt_sub_total_label"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/total"
        android:id="@+id/txt_sub_total"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:hint="@string/total_hint" />

</FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="@string/invoice_btn"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/btn_invoice_save" />

   </LinearLayout>

  < /android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

## invoice product list(getters and setters)

```
   package com.tournonstop.m.invoicemanager;

 public class invoice_product_list {

 private String product_name;
 private double product_price;
private int product_qty;
 private int product_code;

  public invoice_product_list(){

 }

  public invoice_product_list(String product_name,double 
  product_price,int product_qty,int product_code){
  this.product_name = product_name;
  this.product_price = product_price;
  this.product_qty = product_qty;
  this.product_code = product_code;
  }

 public String getProduct_name() {
  return product_name;
 }

   public void setProduct_name(String product_name) {
  this.product_name = product_name;
  }

  public int getProduct_code() {
  return product_code;
 }

  public void setProduct_code(int product_code) {
   this.product_code = product_code;
 }

  public double getProduct_price() {
  return product_price;
 }

  public void setProduct_price(double product_price) {
  this.product_price = product_price;
   }

  public int getProduct_qty() {
  return product_qty;
  }

  public void setProduct_qty(int product_qty) {
  this.product_qty = product_qty;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add item to your list that you're using in adapter and (after verifying adapter is not null ) call method notifyDataSetChanged () on adapter object.

Comment: thanks for replying.. I checked with above answer and adapter is not null and notifyDatasetChanged() is executing. But no changes.. Still it is replacing previous list item.. Even i changed the background color of the listView to see anything is happening. No changes.. Plz help..

Answer (score 0):

**create_invoice activity**

```
 //arraylist
    ArrayList<invoice_product_list> productList = new ArrayList<>();

     //customAdapter
 customAdapterInvoice = new custom_adapter_invoice 
(Create_invoice.this, productList);

            customAdapterInvoice.addProduct(products)
```

**custom Adapter**

```
public class custom_adapter_invoice extends ArrayAdapter <invoice_product_list> 
{
ArrayList<invoice_product_list> productList = new ArrayList<>();
public custom_adapter_invoice(Context context,   
ArrayList<invoice_product_list> product_details) {
super(context, R.layout.custom_row_invoice_item, product_details);
this.productList =product_details
}

public void addProduct(Product products
productList.add(products);
notifyDataSetChanged();
}


 ......
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying bro.. But the thing is still not working.. I've been stuggling from 1 week on same thing but nothing is working. I've a question here bro, Is the switching between the activities are affecting to the listView..?? Can you again look into my question and find the problem... PLz.. thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

No,it does not change anything. If you want the latest method of working then I would prefer RecyclerView to custom list adapter. this link is very good for recyclerview

[recyclerview demo series link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD)